# "co-relatedness" of conditional expectation of two independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation, independence

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra and $X,Y$ be two independent (not just uncorrelated) random variables, I wonder if the following statement true

$$\mathbb E(XY|\mathcal{F})=\mathbb E(X|\mathcal{F})\mathbb E(Y|\mathcal{F}).$$

I have a feeling that it is false but I can't come up with a counterexample. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What restrictions do you have on $F$? If not, then take $F$ to be a $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X+Y$.

Comment: @Boby Sorry but I don't know how to continue. The sigma algebra generated by $X+Y$ looks very foreign to me...

Answer (score 1):

Building on Boby's hint, take $X,Y \overset{iid}{\sim} \mbox{Ber}_{\pm}(1/2)$ and $\mathcal{F} = \sigma(X+Y)$. Then it is easy to compute the conditional expectations:

$
\mathbb{E}[XY| X+Y] = 
\begin{cases}
1, &X+Y = -2\\
-1,& X+Y = 0 \\
1, &X+Y = 2
   \end{cases}
$

On the other hand, we have

$\mathbb{E}[X|X+Y] = \mathbb{E}[Y|X+Y]=
\begin{cases}
-1 &X+Y = -2\\
0,& X+Y = 0 \\
1, &X+Y = 2
\end{cases}
$

Thus we see that a.s. $\mathbb{E}[XY|X+Y] \ne 0$, whereas $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{F}]\cdot \mathbb{E}[Y| \mathcal{F}] = 0$ with probability $1/2$.